# HTML E CSS - CABEÇALHO

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Não consigo por cor tanto na imagem quanto no texto. Tipo uma barra.. do cabeçalho.

```css
.topo {
  background-color: azure;
}

.img {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.titulo-principal,
p {
  font-size: "Open Sans Condensed", "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="topo">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img" />
  <h1 class="titulo-principal">Hostsite VH</h1>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas consequatur odit assumenda, rerum</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: Tente explicar melhor a pergunta. Não consegui compreender o que você quer fazer

Comment: Gostaria de fazer um cabeçalho com uma cor de fundo, e deixar a imagem na parte de baixo um pouquinho fora desse fundo. No jeito que eu fiz aqui, fico só o texto com o fundo da cor que botei ali, e a linha da imagem não.

Comment: Teria como vc Editar sua pergunta e incluir uma imagem do layout que pretende? Pelo que entendi vc quer que um pedaço da imagem fique sobre a cor de fundo e que uma outra parte da imagem fique para fora dessa cor de fundo, é isso?

Comment: Exatamente isso. Botei a imagem agora de como ta ficando. Mas quero que aquela cor azulzinha ali pegue a imagem também e uma parte da imagem fique fora do azul .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, a que eu acho que vai ser mais adequado é colocar na imagem `position:absolute` e ajustar ela na posição usando `top` e `left`

Segue o exemplo

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.topo {
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 25%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
}

.titulo-principal,
p {
  font-size: "Open Sans Condensed", "Arial", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header class="topo">
  <img class="img" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
  <h1 class="titulo-principal">Hostsite VH</h1>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas consequatur odit assumenda, rerum</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Fiz no meu e continua a mesma coisa :/

Comment: @thaty vc colocou position:relative na classe .top ? Se vc copiou exatamente o código que eu coloquei aqui não teria como não ter funcionado ai tb...

Comment: Acho que consegui. Na verdade não estou satisfeita com o logo hahaha, e outras coisinhas. Mas muito obrigada pela ajuda, de verdade!

Comment: @thaty no inicio é assim mesmo, depois com o tempo vc vai descobrindo como fazer no código exatamente as coisas que estão no layout. É preciso tempo e prática... Se vc acredita que essa resposta resolveu o seu problema considere marca-la como aceita nesse ícone `✔`. Assim ela não fica pendente no site como pergunta não resolvida. Vc pode remover esse voto a qualquer momento caso queira, ou coloca-lo em outra resposta que surja e vc ache mais adequado pro seu caso. E pode perguntar no site sempre que precisar, só lembre de incluir na pergunta todos os detalhes, código e imagem se for o caso ;)

Comment: Obrigada, hugo!